# C# Reading Excel file with many rows

Tags: c#, excel

I am a newbie to c#, and I am trying to make a simple program that reads all the rows from an excel file, and put them in an array or some other data storage in c#, so I can make manipulations on this data.

what is the best strategy to do so with c#, with large excel files (about 200,000 rows)?

just go line by line from the excel file, copy it to a DataSet in c# and then manipulate the DataSet with loops?

are there any good examples you can point on?

thank you

Comment: You might want to read row by row using `Interop.Office.Excel` library. Learn about `Range`

Comment: I would look at the EPPlus opensource library to see if that fits your requirements.  It's much nicer to use than interop.

Comment: is there any way doing it without importing new libraries? just using the standart c# libs?

Comment: You can use the COM interop libraries to read from Excel, but they're not very nice to use.

Comment: @Darren Young do you have an example code snippet of how to do it?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, you can add it as an assembley reference, i beleieve its under microsoft office core and it is very good with Excel

an example would be something like this:

***Your excel path***

```
        Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"yourfilepathandname.xls")

        int rCount = XLRangeTable.Rows.Count;
        int cCount = XLRangeTable.Columns.Count;


        object[,] Table = XLRangeTable.Value2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= cCount; i++)
        {
            T.Columns.Add((string)Table[1, i]);
        }
        for (int j = 2; j <= rCount; j++)
        {
            DataRow R = T.NewRow();
            for (int i = 1; i <= cCount; i++)
            {
                R[i - 1] = Table[j, i];
            }
            T.Rows.Add(R);
```

Have fun!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, a few notes: what do you mean by saying "use it as an assembley reference"? and in the code you gave, where is the xl file I am working on?

Comment: If you "Add Reference" in your project to the assembly mentioned, it should become clear.  There is an "open file" function, and from there you should be able to get a sheet, that contains rows/columns.

Comment: My apologies, you would have to declare your excel workbook as follows: Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"yourfilepathandname.xls");

Comment: @Neil - what's "add refernce"? and I know the "open file" function, though I dont understand which variable in here gets the file? is it the XLRangeTable?

Comment: @danijinji i have updated the answer, i would be grateful if you accept it if it works

Comment: @Nonagon thank you for your help, I am still struggling with it. as I said I am new to c#, I know php and java, but this is a bit new to me, so I am trying to figure out how to put everything together.

Comment: C# and PHP are very different but luckily, we have good old MSDN to help out

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa664628(v=vs.71).aspx check this out, you will get the hang of it in no time i promise

Comment: @Nonagon if you open up Solution Explorer, expand your project, there should be a branch that says "References" (underneath Properties).  if you right click on "References", you can select "Add reference".  This will open a "Reference Manager" dialog.  Press "Browse", then find excel.exe (probably somewhere in Program files\Microsoft Office).